# javax.persistence.Tuple.get(java.lang.String) is no accessor method

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

below is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version "3.3"
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version "${jibVersion}"
}

group = 'com.vsi.postgrestoattentive'

if (!project.hasProperty('buildName')) {
    throw new GradleException("Usage for CLI:" 
        + System.getProperty("line.separator") 
        + "gradlew <taskName> -Dorg.gradle.java.home=<java-home-dir> -PbuildName=<major>.<minor>.<buildNumber> -PgcpProject=<gcloudProject>"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "<org.gradle.java.home> - OPTIONAL if available in PATH"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "<buildName> - MANDATORY, example 0.1.23")
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "<gcpProject> - OPTIONAL, project name in GCP";
}

project.ext {
    buildName = project.property('buildName');
}

version = "${project.ext.buildName}"

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

apply from: 'gradle/sonar.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/tests.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/image-build-gcp.gradle'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.0'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test:4.3.0'
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:4.1.1.RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.14.1'
    implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-datadog', version: '1.7.0'
    
}

bootJar {
    archiveFileName = "${project.name}.${archiveExtension.get()}"
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}


test {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.8"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
}
```

We  use javax.persistence.Tuple in our code for fetching data from postgres.It works fine but as soon as i change springboot version from '2.7.5' to '2.3.4.RELEASE' i get following error

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invoked method public abstract java.lang.Object javax.persistence.Tuple.get(java.lang.String) is no accessor method!
at org.springframework.data.projection.Accessor.(Accessor.java:50) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]**

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Sounds like a bug that was fixed in some in-between spring version. If everything works with 2.7.5, is there a reason you want to downgrade to an earlier version?

Comment: i want to use env variables in kubernetes and it works properly in 2.3.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Update Javax to Jakarta, that works for me.